# Astro JS + Tailwind / Classes From Typescript not getting Included

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, rollup, astrojs

I'm trying to build out a single static component in Astro.build that has previously been built in Svelte, but I'm not sure I have my environment properly setup. I have an imported TS file that returns an object with my tailwind classes. Essentially I get back an object that looks like this:

```
tailwind = {
 wrapper: 'container mx-auto',
 headline: 'text-4xl sm:text-6xl lg:text-7xl'
}
```

There is no weirdness in that function like `'text' + var + 'xl'` it's just simply concatenating classes.

Then in my astro component I deconstruct the props `{ wrapper, headline } = tailwind();` so that I can assign them to elements like `<div class={wrapper}>`

This all works fine and my source HTML has all the classes I want. However my CSS file does not include the classes unless I first add them to the astro component directly.

for example if I first add  and then change it to `<div class={wrapper}>` it all works fine, but if I were to add `bg-blue-500` to what `wrapper` returns I do not get a blue background.

I should note this process works great in Svelte so I think it's something with my vite settings, but honestly I get a little lost when it comes to the roll up process. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Tailwind dynamically generates the CSS output, it needs to know the location of all files with Tailwind Classes.

From https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

> The `content` section of your `tailwind.config.js` file is where you configure the paths to all of your HTML templates, JavaScript components, and any other source files that contain Tailwind class names.

Add the `.ts` file to the `content` section of your Tailwind config file.